# Two while for the same query

Tags: php, sql, mysql, mysqli

If I have to loop results of a query echoing first all fields of a column, then echoing something not to loop, then fields of another column.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect();
echo 'Latest users who tried our test<br>';
//select the fields of the first column
$query1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT user FROM ris_uinversita LIMIT 0,10");
//loop the results
while($assoc1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)){echo $assoc1['user'].'<br>';}
//echo something not to loop
echo 'Users got the following scores<br>';
//select the fields of the second column
$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT score FROM ris_universita LIMIT 0,10");
//loop the results
while($assoc2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)){echo $assoc2['score'].'<br>';}
?>
```

Is it possible to use just one query like this

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ris_universita LIMIT 0,10");
```

to select both fields just once?

If it could be helpful, table `ris_universita` has just the two columns: "score" (`tinyint`) and "user" (`varchar 30`).  There aren't so many records for now, but I hope in there will be in the future.

Comment: You are aware that `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` rarely makes good sense?

Comment: I thought that, if not specified, results would have been ordered from the latest inserted to the first one, probably I'm wrong. I'm editing my table adding an unique id and the code. Thanks.

Comment: @Angelo - If you don't specify `ORDER BY`, the optimizer will return rows in whatever order it feels like.  If either one of those columns starts an index, it's probably going to start with that.  A pair of queries is unlikely to match users and scores.  Don't rely on auto-generated ids for insertion order, especially for concurrent systems and anything with triggers: they can only be relied upon to give you a unique value.  Use an `insertedAt` timestamp column for that information (which also makes updating erroneous rows easier).

Comment: Ok, thanks for your advice, I'm gonna do as you said

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to keep identical output, rather than use two loops I would just use two buffers:

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect();
$users = '';
$scores = '';
$userScoreQuery = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT user, score FROM ris_uinversita LIMIT 0,10');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userScoreQuery)){
    $users  .= $row['user' ].'<br>';
    $scores .= $row['score'].'<br>';
}
echo 'Latest users who tried our test<br>'.$users.'Users got the following scores<br>'.$scores;
?>
```

This insures the users actually correspond to the scores and there was not a database change in between two queries.

From a UX perspective I might consider changing your format to a table:

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect();
echo '<h3>Latest Results</h3><table><thead><tr><th>Users</th><th>Scores</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
$userScoreQuery = mysqli_query($connection,'SELECT user, score FROM ris_uinversita LIMIT 0,10');
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($userScoreQuery)){
    echo '<tr><td>'.htmlentities($row['user']).'</td><td>'.htmlentities($row['score']).'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</tbody></tabel>';
?>
```

This allows for easy matching of user to score and for easier css styling. (the thead and tbody elements can be eliminated depending on your css.)

Also note the use of [`htmlentities`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), this may or may not be required depending on your database design, but just in case a user can be named `<script ...` you should use it regardless of desired format.

Also as mentioned in the question comments you should use an ORDER BY cause and add a timestamp column that defaults to current timestamp to your table.

Answer (score 11):

A few things here:

### Comments:

Your comments are all compeletely useless.. nothing personal and no offense. That is a beginner-mistake. You don't need to comment everything.

Comments should explain the **why** and not the **how** or the **what**. Exceptions:

1. License comments
2. Documentation (python's docstring, java's javadoc, c#'s summary, ...)

### Naming:

> ```
> $con = //...
> $query1 = //...
> $assoc1 = //...
> ```

As opposed to what many people seem to think, **source code characters are not costly.** Spell it out:

```
$connection = //...
$userQuery = //...
$userRecord = //...
```

### Formatting:

The convention is, to place *subordinate* blocks in a visually different place than surrounding code. This is usually done by indenting the block and putting it on a separate starting line

> ```
> while($assoc1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)){echo $assoc1['user'].'<br>';}
> ```

then becomes:

```
while ($userRecord = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userQuery)) {
    echo $userRecord['user'].'<br>';
}
```

This would definitely improve the readability of your code, as one line is not a whole loop! Putting too much on one line makes it extremely difficult to follow the thoughts behind your code and makes reading a pain.

Answer (score 7):

## Spaces are free!

It's a good idea to space out your code for readability. @Vogel612 did this in his answer (perhaps subconsciously), but it doesn't hurt to say it explicitly.

## `SELECT` multiple columns without `*`.

You mentioned using `SELECT *`. This is typically considered poor design; it's preferable to explicitly list the columns you want `SELECT`ed, so you can do `SELECT user, score`. (This is because if you add many more columns but you don't use them, you're making the database engine do more work. It also makes it easy to see what columns exist and are used, whereas `SELECT *` will force you to look it up.)

## Design your database carefully.

There is *rarely* a good reason to not include an `id` primary key column in a table. It allows for future cross-referencing as well as performance improvements. Since you want the latest users, then you should also include a `TIMESTAMP`-typed column defaulting to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Then you'll be able to rewrite your query as `` SELECT `user`, `score` FROM `ris_universita` ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 10 ``. Note that you don't need to `SELECT` the `id` column here.

## Be consistent with string delimiters.

You use single quotes and double quotes interchangeably. Since you are neither using string interpolation, nor avoiding escape codes, nor printing out single- or double quotes, you have no reason to use one over the other. Just pick one that you like and use it throughout.

---

The other answers provided excellent points that I tried not to repeat. (The point on comments is especially important.) Here I propose an alternative solution to using a buffer: [`mysqli_data_seek`](http://php.net/mysqli_data_seek). This would save on a little bit of memory compared to the buffer solution, which could be significant if you were selecting millions of rows rather than ten. However, this is probably still not as good as just using a table, as @Rick suggested.

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect();
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT `user`, `score` FROM `ris_universita` ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 10');

    echo 'Latest users who tried our test:<br>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['user'], '<br>';
    }

    mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);
    echo 'Users got the following scores:<br>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['score'], "<br>";
    }
?>
```

Or with error checking, string interpolation, and cleanup, written OO-style:

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli();
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: $mysqli->connect_error\n";
        return; // in case this file is included, return is probably better than die
    }

    $query = "SELECT `user`, `score` FROM `ris_universita` ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 10";
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        echo "Latest users who tried our test:<br />\n";
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "$row[user]<br />\n";
        }

        $result->data_seek(0);
        echo "Users got the following scores:<br />\n";
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "$row[user]<br />\n";
        }

        $result->close();
    } else {
        echo "Query failed: $query";
    }
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to access both columns in the same loop?

```
query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT user, score FROM ris_universita");
while ($assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) {
    echo $assoc['user'];
    echo $assoc['score'];
}
```

You could also use `"SELECT * FROM ris_universita"`, but as Schism mentions in the comments below, you should not do that. Read [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3639964/3719266) for why.

Comment: Thanks, but in the middle of $assoc['user'] and $assoc['score'] I have to insert a string not to be looped

Comment: @Angelo and what about it? Why not echo that first? why do you want to keep users and scores separated?

Comment: What do you mean not to be looped?

Comment: @hansn `echo "Users got the following scores:`, between the while loops.

Comment: @Vogel612 oh, I get it. Then he will need two loops.

Comment: @Vogel612 It was because I had a certain structure of the site I'm building on my mind (put users and scores on right or left with the main content on center, so it would have been better if the sidebar was less wide), but maybe you're right, not to separate the two columns would be handier.

Comment: Downvote for `SELECT *`. Well, I can't actually (insufficient rep), but pretend I did.

Comment: @Schism Why? OP specifically asked if it was possible.

Comment: @hansn That's like if I asked if I could get off a building by jumping off the 2nd-storey balcony. Sure I could, but your answer should include "don't do that; use the stairs!" `SELECT *` is not a good solution so you should explain that  (and why) in your answer.

Comment: @Schism you're right. I edited my post.